# matlab to c++ conversion

Tags: c++, matlab, converters

So i have this matlab code and i'm trying to convert it in c++. The problem is that i don't know to much about matlab. Can someone explain some things to me.
This is my code

```
function [L,D]=ldlt(A)
%
%  Figure out the size of A.
%
n=size(A,1);
%
% The main loop.
%
L=zeros(n,n);
for j=1:n,
  if (j > 1),
    v(1:j-1)=L(j,1:j-1).*d(1:j-1);
    v(j)=A(j,j)-L(j,1:j-1)*v(1:j-1)';
    d(j)=v(j);
    if (j < n),
      L(j+1:n,j)=(A(j+1:n,j)-L(j+1:n,1:j-1)*v(1:j-1)')/v(j);
    end;
  else
    v(1)=A(1,1);
    d(1)=v(1);
    L(2:n,1)=A(2:n,1)/v(1);    
  end;
end;
%
%  Put d into a matrix.
%
D=diag(d);
%
%  Put ones on the diagonal of L.
%
L=L+eye(n);
```

For example how can i write this line in c++

```
L(j+1:n,j)=(A(j+1:n,j)-L(j+1:n,1:j-1)*v(1:j-1)')/v(j);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should help you figure out the code and convert it to either C or C++:

1. If i and j are integers, i:j is a vector of consecutive integers starting from i and going upto j.
2. i:s:j is a vector starting from i and going at most upto j in steps of s.
3. If v is a vector, v(i:j) is then vector of elements of v starting from the i-th index and going upto the j-th index.
4. Matlab indexing starts from 1 unlike C++. There cannot be negative indices.
5. v = zeros(n,1) creates a (column) matlab vector of length n, initialized with 0's
6. L = zeros(n,n) creates an (n x n) matlab matrix initialized to 0's.
7. L(i:j, k:l) is a matrix formed from rows i to j and columns k to l of L.
8. Matrices (and other higher dimensional arrays) are stored in column major form (the first index is the fastest changing one).
9. If A and B are matrices, A*B is the matrix product of A and B.
10. A.*B is the elementwise product of A and B.
11. Matlab has a "Coder" toolbox that converts matlab code (provided it satisfies some restrictions) directly into C. Given the type of code you have pasted, it is a good candidate for direct conversion.
12. If you don't want to auto convert, you will have to implement all the binary operations used by writing loops (or use a C++ matrix library).
13. You can write .mex files in C++ that can be used directly by matlab after compiling them with the matlab mex command. You will need a C++ compiler installed and set it up with mex -setup.

Comment: one quick question thought..L(j,1:j-1) this mean elements from line j and column from 1 to j-1?

Comment: Welcome. That is right. I've used the term "row" for "line".

Answer (score -1):

use this command:

> > mcc -m name_of_file 
> >     mbuild -setup
> >     you will find the .exe in the current folder, if you dont know where you are ??
> >     use this command 
> >     pwd